# Make iframe immediately run when site is launched

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open the site I want the iframe to immediately run code that I have already put in (`<p>hello</p>`).

But the code doesn't get executed, I have to put a space or do something before it runs.

If you can't get that to work, a `run` button will also work.

```js
function compile() {
  var html = document.getElementById("html");
  var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

  document.body.onkeyup = function() {
    code.open();
    code.writeln(
      html.value
    );
    code.close();
  };
}

compile();
```

```css
#html {
  width: 95em;
}

textarea {
  width: 32%;
  float: top;
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f4f4f9;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

iframe {
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code Editor</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="html">&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
  <iframe id="code"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried window.onload=compile();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that writes to the iframe is within an onkeyup event. Nothing will be written until a key is pressed and released. To solve your problem, simply write to the iframe outside of the onkeyup event when the compile function is called as in the example below.

```
function compile() {
    var html = document.getElementById("html");
    var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

    code.open();
    code.writeln(html.value);
    code.close();

    document.body.onkeyup = function() {
        code.open();
        code.writeln(html.value);
        code.close();
   };
}

compile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function to make it say `.onload` instead of `.onkeyup` like this:

```
function compile() {
    var html = document.getElementById("html");
    var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

    document.body.onload = function() {
        code.open();
        code.writeln(
            html.value
        );
        code.close();
    };
}

compile();
```

You could also add a second function with a different name that does the same thing as the original function so that it still changes when you change the code:

```
function change() {
    var html = document.getElementById("html");
    var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

    document.body.onkeyup = function() {
        code.open();
        code.writeln(
            html.value
        );
        code.close();
    };
}

change();
```